# PHP Add comma to every item but last one

Tags: php, csv, for-loop

I have a loop like

```
foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

And I want to add a comma in between each item so it ends up like this.

```
var1, var2, var3
```

Since I am using `foreach` I have no way to tell what iteration number I am on.

How could I do that?

Comment: No way? You can add a counter to your code manually.

Comment: shouldn't his result be `name: var1, name: var2, name: var3` then?

Comment: Sorry for my oversight, I did not look all the way through my snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I did not state my question properly.
The awnser that worked for me is

```
implode(', ', $_GET);
```

Thanks, giodamelio

Comment: woah you are only 14.  nice keep at it bro.

Comment: @kjy112 Thanks I definitely will. Programming is awesome :)

Answer (score 43):

Just build your output with your `foreach` and then implode that array and output the result :

```
$out = array();
foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) {
    array_push($out, "$name: $value");
}
echo implode(', ', $out);
```

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr, Your array would need to be quite large to have an impact on performance, really. And if you have such a huge array, why would want to have a comma-separated string of your items? It all depends on the context, here. In the wonderful world of coding, there is no such thing as a magical one-size-fit-all solution. I invite you to ask a related question, describing your exact problem if *this* is not a workable solution for you.

Comment: I dont have this issue really, was just checking the possibility with large arrays if someone wanted to build a `CSV`, lets say.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr, for CSV, you'd use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), with a combination of [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)... and if you are, then, concerned about huge arrays, then perhaps your approach is just wrong :) Bottom line, let's not enter speculations and ask questions when real concerns arise. Otherwise, we'd never stop talking about use case exceptions. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
$total = count($_GET);
$i=0;
foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) {
    $i++;
    echo "$name: $value";
    if ($i != $total) echo', ';
}
```

Explained: you find the total count of all values by count(). When running the foreach() loop, you count the iterations. Inside the loop you tell it to echo ', ' when the iteration isn't last (isn't equal to total count of all values).

Answer (score 5):

```
$comma_separated = implode(", ", $_GET);

echo $comma_separated;
```

you can use implode and achieve that

Comment: thought he just want the values

Comment: It has to be an array to start with otherwise this will not work.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it this way:

```
$output = '';
foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) {
    $output = $output."$name: $value, ";
}
$output = substr($output, 0, -2);
```

Which just makes one huge string that you can output. Different methods for different styles, really.

Answer (score 0):

I'd typically do something like this (pseudo code):

```
myVar

for... {
    myVar = i + ","
}

myVar = trimOffLastCharacter(myVar)

echo myVar
```